# transparent .gif image not allowing background CSS element to show through

Tags: css, background, transparency

I've just got a quick question that if you have time would be great to have answered.

I'm working on a new site for a woman that is a fixed width site.  She wants her background image to take up the entire span of the browser window and then the image that sits on top -  she wants to be transparent so that the background can show through.

I've got the background image to take up the entire window but for some reason the transparent gif is not behaving as it usually does.  The transparent image is the entire left half of the site.

Any ideas on this?

http://www.winteradagency.com/Arvin/test-bg.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the CSS background color from both #container and #homeLeft.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your CSS states

```
background-color: #D0D9A4;
```

for `#homeLeft`. Simply drop that.

Comment: the color is still present on the #container div, only removing both to get the desired effect.